# selecting invalid dates

Tags: mysql

In the following example, I am getting all the values greater than '2009-11-29' as well as NULL and '0000-00-00'. Is there any other way to get the same results?

```
mysql>select * from totest;
+---------------------+
| stime               |
+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
| 2009-12-12 12:22:32 | 
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
| 2009-01-12 12:22:32 | 
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
| NULL                | 
+---------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>select * from totest where If(stime!='0000-00-00', stime >= '2009-11-29', 1);
+---------------------+
| stime               |
+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
| 2009-12-12 12:22:32 | 
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
| NULL                | 
+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: have you tried or "OR" ?

Comment: May you clarify your question? What you want to return 1) Invalid (zero) and null dates? 2) Select 'correct' dates greater than '2009-11-29'

Comment: I was looking for "OR". Sometimes things are so simple and in front of your eyes and you still don't see them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting invalid dates (zero dates and null)

```
      select * from totest 
      where stime = '0000-00-00' 
        OR stime IS NULL
```

Selecting only valid dates greater than '2009-11-29'

```
      select * from totest 
      where stime != '0000-00-00' 
        AND stime IS NULL
        AND stime >= '2009-11-29'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this out?

```
select *
from totest
where 
    stime = '0000-00-00'
    OR stime IS NULL
    OR stime < '2009-11-29'
```